# MS Word Can't Edit/Delete Macros (Buttons Are Greyed Out)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm having a problem with MS Word 2010 where I have some macros that I can't edit or delete. I'd like to delete them, but in the Macros dialog box, the edit and delete buttons are greyed out. I can run them though. When I try to step into them, I get an error message saying, "Project is unviewable."

I've tried to rename the Normal.dotm file (because I think this is where they're stored) and delete the Normal.dotm file. I've tried going into the VBA editor to access the macros from there, but when I expand the Normal project, I get the same message: "Project is unviewable." I've even tried to uninstall and reinstall Word, but my macros come back.

I've checked Google for solutions, but whether it's macro permissions or a problem with Normal.dotm, no suggestions are working. Does anybody know the solution? If even a complete Office reinstall doesn't work, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems I've found the solution. I deleted the wrong Normal.dotm--the one from my own user account--and not the global one. There was one hiding in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\STARTUP, and once I deleted that and reloaded Word, Word recreated the template from scratch and the unwanted macros were gone.

Thanks to everyone who helped/looked for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

So you are unable to remove macros from MS Word.  First, you need to open the Microsoft VBA Editor.  Then, you need to locate the Project tab.  This will contain the hierarchy of your MS Word doc and macros.

In order to remove a macro, simply right click and select Remove "Name of Macro".

Comment: I can't do that either. From the VBA Editor, in the Project tab, anything I try to do to that project gives me the message "Project is unviewable." I can't even expand the project to get at the macros.